# Compiling Arduino IDE from source throws errors

Tags: electron, yarnpkg, arduino-ide, theia

I'm running Ubuntu and I am following the [Arduino's Github guide](https://github.com/arduino/arduino-ide/blob/main/docs/development.md) on how to compile the IDE, but `yarn` is failing.

I installed all the dependencies needed that are listed on the above page, as well as [Theia's Prereqs](https://github.com/eclipse-theia/theia/blob/master/doc/Developing.md#prerequisites)

**Issue**
When executing yarn in the repo root, it fails wih the following:

```
arduino-ide-extension: task: Failed to run task "go:build": exit status 127
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.

 —————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————

 >  Lerna (powered by Nx)   Running target "prepare" failed

   Tasks not run because their dependencies failed or --nx-bail=true:
   
   - electron-app:prepare
   
   Failed tasks:
   
   - arduino-ide-extension:prepare

error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
```

Why is go needed and why does `go:build` fail?

I'm running `go1.18.1`. Is a different version needed?

**Prerequisites**

```
$ lsb_release -d
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
$ pkg-config --version
0.29.2
$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 11.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.3.0
$ make --version
GNU Make 4.3
$ node --version
v18.13.0
$ npm --version
8.19.3
$ yarn --version
1.22.19
$ go version
go version go1.18.1 linux/amd64
```